# VBA copy formatting from a row to several rows

Tags: vba, excel

Alright so I am really close to getting this but I am just trying to make it work better. I want to copy row 2 formatting that goes until like Column H. The data only goes until Column H. So my code copies ONLY row 2 until Column H. But when it goes to paste, it highlights the whole sheet besides row 1 and it looks like it copies the formatting across the whole thing. It is not really an issue but I would rather know how to make it paste only in the rows and columns I want for future reference. I only want it going to cells that have data in it basically. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
    Range("A2", Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).COPY
    Range("A2", Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Rows.Count is the total number of rows in the sheet, not the number of *occupied* rows.

Comment: I thought that was what xlUp or xlDown did then? Find the last occupied cell or something? I found my code and it was using xlUp instead of Down but it was only copying to the TOP 2 rows. I changed it to xlDown and now it does everything below.

Comment: You are going "down" starting at the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: hmm Well THAT won't work will it!?? haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range


With ActiveSheet
    Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    Set rngPaste = .Range(.Range("A2"), _
                       .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize( , rngCopy.Columns.Count)

End With

rngCopy.Copy
rngPaste.PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. What is the main difference between this and my code? Is it just you put in the resize statement to change what column it goes to? I am trying to figure out how things work more. Thanks!

Comment: Really just the changes around which range is selected for pasting. Also it's good practice to always specify a worksheet when you use Range/Cells, otherwise they end up referring to whatever happens to be the active sheet, and that can make your code brittle and prone to doing odd things.

Comment: Yeah I was still working on fixing that up. Thanks for the help!